# dynamic css with div

Tags: css, reveal.js

Using [this plugin](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/build-a-popup-modal-window-using-the-jquery-reveal-plugin/) to generate a message box. I have the problem with this css :

```
#modal{
visibility:hidden;
width:360px;
height:169px;
padding:8px;

.......
}
```

It worked well if I create a static div with `#modal` but when I create a dynamic div `#modal + ID` then the style does not work.

how to create a dynamic css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Change the css to class and add that class to any no of div.
css will be changed  as follows

```
.modal{
visibility:hidden;
width:360px;
height:169px;
padding:8px;

.......
}
```

Add the class name in the div

```
<div class="modal">
```

Comment: I totally forgot about `class` in CSS. It worked now. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing the div I'd then you have to change the CSS selector too to #modal + I'd, also for example `#modal1`